# Science fiction story about two species on a planet with two gods

Tags: story-identification, aliens, space

On a planet two species that look nothing alike exist together.
Two gods govern the planet.
Each god has a veil over their species so that they look like each other.
Two different species fall in love.
The gods war and the veils are destroyed and they see each other in their real shape.

Comment: Was this a short story or a novel? And in roughly which year did you read it?